# Office 365 PowerPoint - Hitting Tab in Bullet List Doesn’t Indent

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, office365

I’ve seen this raised either for Word or for earlier versions of PowerPoint, where the solution is to enable the Auto-Correct as you type property “Set left- and first-indent with tabs and backspaces”.

That option is not available for this version of PowerPoint. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're talking about indenting to the next lower bullet level, as opposed to just indenting the text, tabbing only works fully on text that's in placeholders, not with text in inserted text boxes or other shapes. For those it only halfway works, and then only in recent versions of PPT; in older versions you had to use the indent buttons on the ribbon to get even to halfway.